# CSS Sprite Selector

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I'm trying to use css sprite for reducing request count but i have problem. In every span element all 4 icons are showing.

```
.sprite {
    background-image: url("img/spritesheet.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
}
.sd-tabber .sdt-nav li span.episodes:before{
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-position: -31px -5px;
}

.sd-tabber .sdt-nav li span.reviews:before{
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-position: -5px -31px;
}

.sd-tabber .sdt-nav li span.forum:before{
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-position: -5px -31px;
}

.sd-tabber .sdt-nav li span.wallpapers:before{
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-position: -31px -31px;
}

.sd-tabber .sdt-nav li span.cast:before{
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-position: -5px -5px;
}
```

And my HTML

```
<div class="sd-tabber tnTabber">
     <ul id="dizi-ul" class="sdt-nav tnNav">
          <li class="active"><span class="episodes">Bölümler</span></li>
          <li><span class="sprite reviews">Yorumlar</span></li>
          <li><span class="sprite wallpapers">Resimler</span></li>
          <li><span class="sprite cast">Oyuncular</span></li>
          <li><span class="sprite forum">İncemeler</span></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

I triend to play with selectors but no result. It seems OK to me. How can i fix that issue? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selectors are wrong, 
see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/L9xyc6z5/) fiddle, I only changed the selectors. Because your selectors werent right only the css for .sprite was used.

```
  .sprite {
    background-image: url("http://img01.deviantart.net/0adf/i/2012/279/6/6/zero_sprite_sheet_small_update_by_xxxzero8-d5h03st.png");
    display: block;
}
.reviews{
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-position: -31px -5px;
}

.wallpapers{
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-position: -5px -31px;
}

.cast{
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-position: -5px -31px;
}

.forum{
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-position: -31px -31px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it is working. I think i need to practise more about selectors :)